# Can I use a Office Professional plus 2013 code to get skydrive pro

Tags: onedrive, microsoft-office-2013, office365

Can I use a Office Professional Plus 2013 Product Key to get the 20GB of skydrive storage or do I have to have a 365 subscription to get the 20GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only bundled with Office 365.
Source: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/buy/compare-microsoft-office-products-FX102898564.aspx

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.